# Python - Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

For some reason, whenever I type 'python' into powershell, it tells me that 'python' is not recognized. I know that it works on other people's computers, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I know that this is vague, but I really have no idea what i am supposed to do. I am using the python from python.org. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you add python to your path? Does it work for the regular command prompt or is it powershell specific?

Comment: Also, if you already had powershell running before adding python to your path (through the checkbox in the installer, or the System control panel, etc.), you may need to launch a new powershell instance.

Comment: Type $env:path in powershell and see if the directory for python.exe is in there. If not the other comments have good suggestions.

Comment: In response to Colonel Panic:
It doesn't work in the command prompt either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first with adding python to your path:

```
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\Python\"
```

Note that the path may differ on your machine.

Btw for PS - Python integration you might want to play with IronPython:
[Embedding IronPython in PowerShell](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2008/02/embedding-powershell-in-ironpython.html).

Comment: For some reason, whenever I exit powershell, this undoes itself and I have to type in all the code again. Any ideas why?